# How can I generate samples in Matlab and estimate covariance and eigenvalues?

Tags: matlab, data-mining, covariance, eigenvalue

My problem statement: Generate 10 samples and estimate the covariance and identify its eigenvalues. Repeat this experiment 50 times and compute the mean and the standard deviation of the two eigenvalues estimated across 50 trials.

How can I go about achieving this in Matlab? Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

you haven't specified the number of observations for samples in your question. therefore, the problem can be solved in two ways. generate 10 samples 50 times for the desired number of observations and calculate the eigenvalues, mean, and standard deviation, or generate 10 samples 50 times and concatenate them in every iteration as an observation. Another thing is that I don't understand why you're saying two eigenvalues since the covariance matrix for 10 samples is 10 by 10 and clearly has 10 eigenvalues. so if I understood properly here is the code for the first assumption

```
N = 50;
NumberOfSamples = 10;
NumberOfObservations = 100;
EigOfCovariance = zeros(NumberOfSamples,N);
MeanOfEigs = zeros(N,1);
SigmaOfEigs = zeros(N,1);
for i = 1:N
Samples = rand(NumberOfObservations,NumberOfSamples);
CovarianceOfSamples = cov(Samples);
EigOfCovariance(:,i) = eig(CovarianceOfSamples);
MeanOfEigs(i) = mean(EigOfCovariance(:,i));
SigmaOfEigs(i) = sqrt(var(EigOfCovariance(:,i)));
end
```

and for the second assumption the code is

```
N = 50;
NumberOfSamples = 10;
Samples = rand(1,NumberOfSamples);
EigOfCovariance = zeros(NumberOfSamples,N);
MeanOfEigs = zeros(N,1);
SigmaOfEigs = zeros(N,1);
for i = 2:N
Samples = cat(1,Samples,rand(1,NumberOfSamples));
CovarianceOfSamples = cov(Samples);
EigOfCovariance(:,i) = eig(CovarianceOfSamples);
MeanOfEigs(i) = mean(EigOfCovariance(:,i));
SigmaOfEigs(i) = sqrt(var(EigOfCovariance(:,i)));
end
```

where MeanOfEigs is the vector of means of eigenvalues and SigmaOfEigs is the vector of standard deviation for 50 iterations.